# Ordenar e remover números repetidos arraylist em java

Tags: java

Eu preciso fazer um programa que leia duas listas de inteiros e preencha uma outra lista com todos os elementos das duas listas originais, sem repetição e ordenados. Ao final, mostre as três listas na tela.

Por exemplo: [3,6,5,3,7] [2,9,7,5,1] ==> [1,2,3,5,6,7,9]

Até o momento o código está assim:

```
package array;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import  java.util.Collections;

public class Lista {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> numlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> numlist2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        numlist.add(3);
        numlist.add(6);
        numlist.add(5);
        numlist.add(3);
        numlist.add(7);

        numlist2.add(2);
        numlist2.add(9);
        numlist2.add(7);
        numlist2.add(5);
        numlist2.add(1);

        numlist.addAll(numlist2);
        Collections.sort(numlist);

        System.out.println("Lista");
        System.out.println("\n"+numlist.toString()+"\n\n");


    }
}
```

Comment: Como a pergunta não explica claramente qual o problema não vou adicionar uma resposta, o máximo que me permito o ajudar é com [esse exemplo](https://ideone.com/RnvXCN). Favor [edit] a pergunta e esclarecer o problema para que possam serem apresentadas respostas objetivas. Faça o nosso [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Tente o seguinte:

```
numlist = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(numlist));
```

Converter sua lista para um `Set` fará com que os elementos repetidos sejam automaticamente removidos. Note também que não é necessário converter de volta  para ArrayList, visto que o método `.toString()` de um `Set` retornará o mesmo resultado:

`[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9]`

Juntando tudo, ficaria assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> numlist = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3, 6, 5, 3, 7));
    List<Integer> numlist2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2, 9, 7, 5, 1));

    numlist.addAll(numlist2);
    Collections.sort(numlist);

    System.out.println("Lista: " + new HashSet<>(numlist));
}
```

Note que também fiz as seguintes alterações:

- `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3, 6, 5, 3, 7))` para deixar a instanciação das listas menos verbosa
- `List<Integer>` ao invés `ArrayList<Integer>`, pois é uma boa prática preferirmos as interfaces ao invés de suas implementações
- removi o `.toString()` dentro da concatenação da string, visto que ele será chamado automaticamente

Answer (score 0):

Tem uma classe que faz exactamente isso: `TreeSet<Integer>`.
A classe `TreeSet` armazena um conjunto ordenado de objetos (aqui `Integers`) e o método `add` exclui duplicatas.

Veja a descrição e o exemplo do método `add` [aqui](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/treeset-add-method-in-java/).

```
final TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();

set.add(3);
set.add(6);
set.add(5);
set.add(3);
set.add(7);

set.add(2);
set.add(9);
set.add(7);
set.add(5);
set.add(1);

System.out.println("Lista");
System.out.println("\n" + set.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Nota: No caso de você usar uma classe personalizada em vez de `Integer`, você deve fornecer ao construtor `TreeSet` uma classe implementando `Comparable` para classificação e o método `equals` para teste de exclusividade.
Você também pode dar ao construtor de `TreeSet` um `Comparator` para descrever corretamente como classificar objetos.

Answer (score 0):

Basta usar esse trecho

```
numlist.stream().distinct().toList()
```

e o resultado será

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9]
```